# WCF xs:date using Groovy

Tags: wcf, groovy

I have a WSDL I need to write a WCF client against (in C#). In the WSDL one of the elements is:

```
<xs:element name="TransactionDateTime" type="xs:date" />
```

For the moment I'm using a mock service created through SoapUI with that wsdl, so I can get mock responses where I'm trying to populate that TransactionDateTime using a groovy script.

My problem is whatever I use it seems to raise an exception in the client when trying to deserialize the reply body

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

These are examples of what I've tried to return in the groovy script

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(new Date())

javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance())
```

If I try to hardcode it in the xml that I use as a response as

```
2014-09-11T10:11:555
```

which is by the way the format specified in the docs that came along with the WSDL it raises the same exception

Further more if I just hard code in the response a date like this '2014-09-12' instead of raising an exception it populates it as 01/01/0001 00:00:00 in the DateTime property of the C# class the response is populating

Can anyone give me any hint on which path should I follow?

UPDATE:

Wasn't 100% sure but I reckon the reason is the same as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293336/wcf-client-seeing-xsdate-and-xstime-as-string) or explained in other webs, WCF doesn't support xs:date. So I would ask the third party to change the WSDL and send the date as a string that I will parse. Can't thinkg of a better option