# XML Parser Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using Groovy Script in SOAPUI for a several mock service. I'm trying to modify XML file by groovy script, but It not work. Please help me

I want to change value of `<STATUS>` in this file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns5:PCH1CRTO_REC xmlns:ns2="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/Error" xmlns:ns3="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1CRTI" xmlns:ns4="http://www.csc.smart/msp/schemas/MSPContext" xmlns:ns5="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1CRTO" xmlns:ns6="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1ENQI" xmlns:ns7="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1ENQO">
         <STATUS>0</STATUS>
```

My groovy script in SOAPUI

```
filePath = groovyUtils.projectPath + "\\Response-Client-Details\\Response-Policy-List\\Response-Policy-Details\\" + fileArray[i] + ".xml"
def root = xmlParser.parse(filePath)
```

What I have to do next? I try many ways but it doesn't work, even get value of `<STATUS>`. Thank you

Comment: did it eventually  work?

Comment: not yet, I couldn't write xml file

Comment: I fixed it, due to yesterday is too late for working overtime. I have solution for it! You're a best partner, thank you very much @mitomed

Answer (score 0):

So you have the xml in root variable, now you would need to access your STATUS element using XPath, and update it

Would be something like this (you should as well import groovy.xml.XmlUtil)

```
def soapenv =  new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
def ns5 = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1CRTO")

root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC].[STATUS][0].value = 1
```

for saving it back, try this

```
def outputFile = groovyUtils.projectPath + "\\Response-Client-Details\\Response-Policy-List\\Response-Policy-Details\\" + fileArray[i] + ".xml"
def f = XmlUtil.serialize(root)
def of = new File(outputFile)
of.write(f, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Why only xmlns:ns5="http://www.csc.smart/bo/schemas/PCH1CRTO". Can you explain why? thank you!

Comment: By the way, it doesn't work with exception: No such property STATUS :(

Comment: Can you paste the whole XMl with a couple of more properties? I will try to test it myself

Comment: My XML file is too long too post it as comment, but it's quite simple. Just as same as with on my post. Please help me, I spent all my afternoon for this.

Comment: And Status is not nested under any other of the namespaces defined, right? Just under ns5

Comment: Try log.info [soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC]

Comment: i think it should be `log.info root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC]`, right? I tried and it printed out as same as  `log.info (root)`. In additional, mine is `def root = xmlParser.parse(filePath)` not `def root = xmlParser.parseText(filePath)`

Comment: It works with your way, new value is 1. but it's not saved in file

Answer (score 0):

I found the best answer for this, try this:

```
log.info root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC].STATUS[0].text()
```

not

```
log.info root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC][STATUS][0].text()
```

then save it

```
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filePath))).print(root)
```

Anyway, thank @mitomed so much, you help me a half way!

Comment: Cool, I wasn't sure but just wanted to give you my best hint as myself struggled with this the other day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804789/wcf-xsdate-using-groovy

Comment: But i face to another trouble, I can't update new value for `<STATUS>`? `.value` seems not work. Do you have any idea @mitomed

Comment: When you log it you get the 0?

Comment: `log.info ('VALUE:' + root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC].STATUS[0].text())`

`root[soapenv.Body][ns5.PCH1CRTO_REC].STATUS[0].value = 1`

Like this, but it doesn't work!

Comment: I mean, whith the way you're accessing it now (with the point before the status) is being logged properly as 0?. yo get VALUE: 0?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? explain it clearly :D

Comment: an error: `.value` binary expression. We can't use this way, I think `addTextToNode should` be worked?

Comment: Well, it worked for me as you can see in the link of my question

Comment: it works for me too. But new data is not saved, have any idea? It think `.value` is not enought, it need a method to save data and write in file

Comment: do you know how to write data in xml? I try some ways but not work?

Comment: I tried this
`def writer = new StringWriter()
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(root)
def result = writer.toString()`
But it doesn't work